# Why does SUMIFS not work for this solution?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

Hello I am new to access and was trying to do a practice question from this site
https://excel-practice-online.com/functions/sumifs/

[sumifs problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uKpc8.png)

I tried =SUMIFS(D4:D13,B4:B13,B4,C4:C13,C4) for the answer but it doesn't seem to work help would be appreciated.

Comment: Why do you reference Access? This is an Excel function. "Doesn't seem to work" means what - error message, wrong result, nothing happens?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tested your expression and it works for me. However, could use text instead of cell references for criteria.

`=SUMIFS(D4:D13,B4:B13,"Gold",C4:C13,"NY")`

To reference cells for criteria input, use cells dedicated for that purpose, such as F1 and F2, and enter the values you want:
**Gold**
**NY**

`=SUMIFS(D4:D13,B4:B13,F1,C4:C13,F2)`